# Qt model view architecture between QSlider and QSpinBox

Tags: qt, architecture, view, model, delegates

I'd like share data between a QSlider and a QSpinBox. If I edit one, the other one should get the same value without having to do it manually using the Model View Delegate architecture.

Any idea how to use this architecture with an integer model ?

Thanks

Comment: Are the `QSlider` and `QSpinBox` delegate editors?  If not, you should not be using MVD at all - just use signals/slots.

Comment: I dont even understand what other approach you would want besides signal/slot. These simple widgets only represent values between a lower and upper range. They dont really model any data structures. Just produces value outputs to drive something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but the standard way to do this in Qt is to just use the built-in signals and slots `valueChanged(int)` and `setValue(int)`:

```
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), spinbox, SLOT(setValue(int)));
connect(spinbox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

Note that this won't produce infinite recursion, and at two lines of code, it's pretty darn automatic.

Comment: This is what I use but it was triggering the signals when I use the setters. Now I'm blocking the signals using the blockSignals(true); method.
Thanks.

Comment: @YassirEnnazk You might also want to look into the `QSlider::sliderMoved()` and `QAbstractSpinBox::editingFinished()` signals, which aren't emitted when you use `setValue()`.

Comment: you are right for the sliderMoved() signal however the `QAbstractSpinBox::editingFinished()` is not triggered when I use edit the SpinBox.